# CORS not working for calls from Ajax to ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, ajax, .net-core, cors, asp.net-core-webapi

It throws this error on the Ajax call.
I also tried these lines in Startup.cs with named policy. None of the ways that I found online, works.
I'm sure I'm making some silly mistake somewhere, I'm not seeing it.

```
builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:44380")
builder.WithOrigins("localhost:44380")
builder.WithOrigins("localhost")
[EnableCors("MyPolicy")] //in Controller.cs
```

Error from Chrome Browser Console:
[image]

Controller.cs

```
[Route("api/itexit")]
[EnableCors]
[ApiController]
public class ITExitController : ControllerBase
{
    //code...
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddSwaggerGen();

    services.AddCors();

    string connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
    services.AddDbContext<CoCFormsContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
}
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "CoCForms.API");
    });

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseCors(builder =>
    {
        builder
        .AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader();
    });
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

Ajax call from .cshtml page

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    //dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (data,textstatus,jqXHR) {
//process data
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textstatus, exception) {
//process exception
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the named policy like this:

```
 services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowAnyHeader();
            }));
```

and this

```
 app.UseCors("MyPolicy");
```

And you don't  need [EnableCors] in the controller in this case. You need it only if you use AddDefaultPolicy....

Comment: People usualy use  contentType: 'json', not dataType and maby it isn't relevant but I don't see any action (and any action route)

Comment: And did you swap  AddCors and UseCors?

Comment: My bad, the issue was that the api requires windows authentication. I had to change the code in Startup.cs. I'll post the code as answer

Answer (score -2):

The real issue was that the API requires Windows Authentication. The error really was

> 401.2 UnAuthorized

, which wasn't showing in Chrome Console. I found the "UnAuthorized" error by calling the api from another C# project, not from Ajax call.

After making the following changes, it works now.

Added these additional lines to the Ajax call:

```
crossDomain: true,
xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
},
```

Updated Ajax Call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    success: function (data,textstatus,jqXHR) {
        //process data
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textstatus, exception) {
        //process exception
    }
});
```

Added this line in Startup.cs
replaced `AllowAnyOrigin()` to

```
builder.SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true)
```

and added this line too

```
services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

Updated Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    services.AddSwaggerGen();

    services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", builder =>
    {
        builder.SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true)
               .AllowAnyMethod()
               .AllowAnyHeader()
               .AllowCredentials();
    }));

    string connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
    services.AddDbContext<CoCFormsContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "CoCForms.API");
    });

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseCors("MyPolicy");
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

Added `[Authorize]` attribute to the Controller

```
[Route("api/itexit")]
[ApiController]
[Authorize]
```